# word patterns and prepositional phrases

Tags: pronouns, direct-objects, dummy-pronouns

Which one is correct?

> 1. I can't stand **it** when I lose things.
> 2. I can't stand when I lose things.

I have come across the case when "it" is possible but I still doubt which of the above is correct.

Comment: Yes, I mean I wanna know If I should leave out "it" or not

Comment: Well, of course you can't stand if what you lost were your legs. :)

Comment: It seems that the usage of "stand" that you want is one that needs a direct object. Consider: *"I can't stand my brother when he pokes fun at me", "I can't stand happy people", "I can't stand rainy days", "I can't stand school"*. So, it seems that if a direct object isn't there, then the pronoun "it" is inserted to fulfill that syntactic requirement. That is, the sense of "stand" that is being used is a transitive one, and it needs an object. If the object (e.g. "it") isn't there, then your sentence could be misinterpreted--which is the problem with your 2nd version.

Comment: You can find this usage in dictionaries. For example: [to endure the presence or personality of <can't stand the boss>](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand).

Comment: @F.E. Though I also prefer the first version, this question makes me think maybe it's possible to think of [when I lose things] as a what.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Consider: *"I can't stand my brother when he pokes fun at me"* with *"I can't stand **it** when my brother pokes fun at me"* which uses a dummy "it".

Comment: @F.E. Agree. I would prefer the dummy *it*, too. This question just made me curious if the *when* clause could take the place of *it*. As it turns out, it seems like it can't. Thanks. By the way, (a belated) Happy New Year!

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think this is one of those types of sentences where the dummy "it" is required if the closest complement isn't a NP (but not completely sure)--there are some other cases similar to this, like where a subordinate clause can't be between a verb and another of its complements, and so, direct-object extraposition is required. -- "Happy New Year's, to you too!" :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the first one:

> I can't stand it when I lose things.

The two sentences have a very different meaning. The first means that losing things aggravates you. The second means that you can't physically stand (on your own feet) when you lose something, which is a very unlikely sentence.

Answer (score 1):

As F.E. points out in a comment, this meaning of "stand" sounds most natural when it takes an object.  Thus, the following two sentences sound natural:

> I can't stand it when I lose things.
>
> I can't stand losing things.